# FuelPHP's ORM Package isn't ordering items correctly

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I have a table with a 'title' field, I am trying to get all rows in this table, and order them by the title ASC. The four records I am testing with have the titles:

Another test

My New Page

NEW

aaa

This is also the order the rows are returned which is incorrect. 'aaa' should be at the top of the list. I assume the problem is with the lower and upper case characters.

I want to order by LOWER(title) rather then just title however I am having issues making this work in FuelPHP.

The code I'm using to select the records is:

```
$pages = Model_pages::find('all', array(
    'order_by' => array('title' => 'asc')
));
```

How do I make the code above order items regardless of their 'case'?

EDIT:

@Uru, thanks for the feedback :) I have tried the following code, all variations result in SQL or PHP errors:

```
$pages = Model_pages::find('all', array(
    'order_by' => \DB::expr('LOWER(title) ASC')
));

$pages = Model_pages::find('all', array(
    'order_by' => \DB::expr('LOWER(title)')
));

$pages = Model_pages::find('all', array(
    'order_by' => \DB::expr('LOWER(title) ASC')
));

$pages = Model_pages::find('all', array(
    'order_by' => array( \DB::expr('LOWER(title)') )
));

$pages = Model_pages::find('all', array(
    'order_by' => array( \DB::expr('LOWER(title) ASC') )
));

$pages = Model_pages::find('all', array(
    'order_by' => array( \DB::expr('LOWER(title)') => 'ASC' )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `DB::expr('LOWER(title)')` to escape expressions and use that instead of `'title'`.

If this does not work and there is nothing in the [documentation](http://fuelphp.com/docs) then this feature is currently not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the database collation in MySQL, changing it to utf8_general_ci resolved the issue. Thanks to Harro over at the FuelPHP Forums for answering this one:

> Are you using MySQL? And if so, what collating sequence do you use for
>   your table?
>
> MySQL as collating sequence with "ci" at the end (like
>   utf8_general_ci), which are "case insensitive". Which means "aaa" and
>   "AAA" are sorted equally.
>
> If you want to know what SQL is executed exactly, set 'profiling' to
>   true in your config.php, and set it to true in your database
>   definition, in /db.php.
>
> You will get a little black profiler in the lower right corner of your
>   page, and if you click on it, the profiler will open, and it will show
>   you all SQL queries executed.
>
> There is nothing wrong with you ORM code as far as I can see, but I
>   never use array notation. I would have used (which should generate the
>   same SQL):
>
> $pages = Model_pages::query()->order_by('title', 'asc')->get();

The full thread can be found here for anyone running into the same issue:

http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/13226/fuelphp039s-orm-isn039t-ordering-items-correctly